# Find the smallest subexpression containing all subexpressions matching a given pattern

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-manipulation

I need to write a function that, given an expression like

```
1/x + 1/(Abs[x] + 1/(1 + Abs[y - Abs[x]]))
```

finds all its subexpressions matching a certain pattern (say, `_Abs`) and then returns the *smallest* subexpression containing all of those occurrences. In this example, there are 3 subexpressions matching the pattern (2 of them are identical, but we need to include both of them): `Abs[x]`, `Abs[x]`, `Abs[y - Abs[x]]`, so the smallest subexpression containing all of them is `Abs[x] + 1/(1 + Abs[y - Abs[x]])`.

A more precise definition: An expression containing all occurrences matching a given pattern is the *smallest* if it does not contain a proper subexpression that already contains all of the occurrences. For example, `1/(Abs[x] + 1/(1 + Abs[y - Abs[x]]))` is not the smallest, because it contains a proper subexpression `Abs[x] + 1/(1 + Abs[y - Abs[x]])` that already contains all 3 occurrences.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: `Union@ Level[expr, Infinity]` will give you all the distinct subexpressions. `Cases[expr, _Abs, All]` will give you the instances to look for. After that it's a question of some tedious pattern matching, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should be reasonably efficient:

```
expr = 1/x + 1/(Abs[x] + 1/(1 + Abs[y - Abs[x]]));
Position[expr,_Abs]/.
  {{Longest[pos___],___}...}:>
    Extract[expr,{pos}]
```

This works by first getting the position of all occurrences of the pattern (here `_Abs`). The smallest subexpression containing all of them is then given by the longest common prefix of the positions, which is exactly what we identify using the pattern in the `ReplaceAll` call. Finally, we extract the relevant subexpression.

Answer (score 3):

With your expressions, first extract the terms you seek using `Cases`:

```
expr = 1/x + 1/(Abs[x] + 1/(1 + Abs[y - Abs[x]]));

cases = Cases[expr, _Abs, Infinity]
(* Out: {Abs[x], Abs[x], Abs[y - Abs[x]]} *)
```

Then generate a list of unique subexpressions of your expression at all levels, using [`Level`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Level.html) and `Union` to get a sorted duplicate-free list:

```
subexpressions = Union@Level[expr, Infinity]
(* Out: 
{-1, 1, 1/x, x, y, y - Abs[x], -Abs[x], Abs[x], Abs[y - Abs[x]], 
 1/(1 + Abs[y - Abs[x]]), 1 + Abs[y - Abs[x]], 
 1/(Abs[x] + 1/(1 + Abs[y - Abs[x]])), Abs[x] + 1/(1 + Abs[y - Abs[x]])} *)
```

Now 1) group your expressions *by the types of `Abs` subexpressions* they contain (`GroupBy` by the output of `Cases` on each subexpression); 2) from the resulting association, extract the entry that contains all the desired cases by using the `association[key]` syntax; 3) take the shortest of the subexpressions returned, here defined as the one with the minimal `LeafCount`:

```
MinimalBy[LeafCount]@
  GroupBy[subexpressions, Cases[#, _Abs, Infinity]&][cases]
(* Out: {Abs[x] + 1/(1 + Abs[y - Abs[x]])} *)
```